# Python consequences of reading txt file 600x-1200x per minute

Tags: python, file, text, hardware, corruption

Has reading txt file with python up to 1200x times per minute any consequences of any sort?

I am doing on project where one of the program is in eternal loop and its not very easy to pass it any arguments(dont want to use thread or multiprocessing(pass variables between interpretors) for passing arguments).

(I am using Raspberry pi)

Nature of the code:

```
import time
while True:
    with open('args.txt', 'r') as FILE:
        ARGS = FILE.read()
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

If this isnt safe, is there any better solution how to keep program running while checking every 0.05s for reading some external source of data?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is being written on to this txt file? Is it a python script? Is it a subprocess ?

Comment: It is just 2 -3 words. Based on the words, program decides what to do next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are a linux user you might be familiar with `tail -f filename.txt`.

> Instead of just displaying the last few lines and exiting, tail displays the lines and then monitors the file. As new lines are added to the file by another process, tail updates the display.

[If your usecase is to read newlines appended to a file here's an implementation of `tail -f`.](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/157035-tail-f-in-python/)

```
file = open(filename,'r')
#Find the size of the file and move to the end
st_results = os.stat(filename)
st_size = st_results[6]
file.seek(st_size)
import time
while 1:
   where = file.tell()
   line = file.readline()
   if not line:
       time.sleep(0.05)
       file.seek(where)
   else:
       print line, # already has newline
```

This continuosly checks every 0.05 sec and prints new lines appended.

Alternately here is `tail  -f` as a subprocess:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
p = Popen(["tail", "-f", "/the/file"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
for line in p.stdout:
    print(line)
```

If the file is appended by a subprocess its even easier, just pipe the stdout to your function.

Comment: Thanks, it looks it works nice for appending, but I am not appending new line, I rewrite the first line and that doesnt work.